# Sublime Text - Exclude comments in search

Tags: comments, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Every time I search for a function inside of hundreds of files, I see so many matches for comments which have no effect in the code.

Can someone limit Sublime Text's search scope to real code, and exclude comments?

I use Sublime Text 3 for developing a C++ program.

Comment: I am the person that has offered the +100 bounty. I just leave this comment just in case someone want to use a comment to ask me anything. You can also comment in my answer if you want to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I created a [Plugin](https://gist.github.com/gwenzek/a16d40ba36268ac84716) that search for a given string inside a given scope.
The default scope selector is `-comment` effectively searching outside of comments. The text to search for is taken from the current selection. The results are presented in the drop-down menu

Basically I combined two API methods:

- `view.find_all(pattern)` that searches for a pattern in the given view.
- `view.match_selector(position, scope_selecor)` that check if the given position is inside the given scope.

Comment: Your solution meets all bounty requirements so you deserve the bounty. Good job.

Comment: Thanks, tell me if you need help tweaking it 

Comment: You're welcome. I was trying to modify the plugin to find new words while typing but I was unable to do it. This would be cool, but note that it is not really necessary, at least for me.

Comment: I'm sorry what are you trying to do?  Would you like to type the searched text in a textbox instead of using the current selection?

Comment: I was trying to update the results based on the text in the quick panel.

Comment: Ok, I don't know if that's possible but I'll look into it

Comment: How to install this file in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: @prosti copy paste it in your Packages/User folder. To go there use the 'Browse Package' menu in Sublime

Comment: Here is what I get: `File "/home/dj/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/find_in_scope.py", line 13, in run
pattern = self.pattern
AttributeError: 'FindInScope' object has no attribute 'pattern'`

Comment: @sergioFC I looked a bit and I didn't find a way to be notified in my plugin when the user is typing in the search bar. The menu have to be prepopulated, and the "fuzzy search engine" do the rest

Comment: @gwenzek not really sure if this is working correctly. I get a dropdown menu with all the results. Is this correct? is it possible to use any of the search options such as case sensitive, whole word, etc?

Comment: @gwenzek Stoopid question: Why can't this be done without the plugin?

Answer (score 7):

You could use regex to find patters matching the regex you give.
Design the regex according to match your.

You can give regex by turning on the 'Regular Expression' flag

[image: By this way you can search without comments]

**Example**

You can have this regex to match your case if you want to match alone in single line comments.

```
^(?!\/\/)([^\/\n]*)YOUR_SEARCH_TERM
```

If you want to match also in multi line comments use this.

```
^(?!(\/\/|(\/\*(.|\n)*([^\*])(?=\/))))YOUR_SEARCH_TERM
```

Comment: Comments  have their own complexity. Could you please give a complete answer?

Comment: Now have a look above. @barej

Comment: But it searched in comments too for me : [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uu8h0.png)

Comment: Multi comments not handled earlier. now check the answer above. @barej